# CSS3 Challenge - How to get this gradient background pattern without using all the divs?

Tags: css

I am wondering if some CSS guru can give me some idea of how to build this background pattern without using the div tags as used here - http://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/IrAfF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css would be

```
.back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 99%;
    height: 99%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #6e529d 0%, #d97b93 100%);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.back:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    background-image: linear-gradient(44.9deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 7.18em, transparent 7.16em),
                      linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 7.18em, transparent 7.16em),
                      linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 25%, transparent 25%),
                      linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 25.391%, transparent 25%);
    background-size: 20em 20em;
    background-position: 0em 0em, 10em 10em, 10em 10em, 0em 0em;

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTxMg/)

Another approach, without need to use absolute positioning

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    top: 0px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(44.9deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 7.18em, transparent 7.16em),
                      linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 7.18em, transparent 7.16em),
                      linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 25%, transparent 25%),
                      linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0%, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 25.391%, transparent 25%);
    background-size: 20em 20em;
    background-position: 0em 0em, 10em 10em, 10em 10em, 0em 0em;

}

body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #6e529d 0%, #d97b93 100%);
}
```

And using 100% dimensions :-)

[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/KTxMg/1/)

Comment: Any reason why the width & height are 99%?

Comment: Wow! Amazing...Is it possible to do it on the body/html tag without the absolute positioning? Ideally, it would just be a simple background pattern instead using a textured image

Comment: @ZachSaucier Not really... When I was testing, 100% created scrollbars (probably I had some border - padding somewhere) and I changed it, and later I forgot  to remove it.