# Interpreting CSS3 linear gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I found a way to make an awesome background on [this site](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon) and I want to understand what is going on with the CSS. There is a lot going on and I want to be able to duplicate it with other things. Here are some sites that I have found that describe the basics:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient, 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

but none of them describe something as complex as this. Will someone please walk me through only the linear gradient lines? Why are there multiple linear-gradients? What do the arguments outside of the linear-gradients' parenthesis mean?

The CSS:

```
background:
linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
background-color: #131313;
background-size: 20px 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This technique uses 2 components:

a) Having defined a background-size of 20px by 20px (last line), you define a square of those dimensions. This will act as a frame that will cut the..

b) linear gradient, at a given angle, and going from a color to transparent.

This creates, most of the time, a triangle. (you can create a trapezoid if you go beyond the corner in the gradient dimension)
[image: gradient]

Notice that you can get any corner of the basic square adjusting the gradient angle

The background that you have post contains basically 6 triangles.

What remains to create an interesting layout is the ability to position the different triangles that you got. This are the 2 parameters after the gradient colors, the position given as x and y coordinate.

I used this technique in some answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186847/1926369)  or, a fairly complex one,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208496/1926369)

Play with and experiment, that is the way to learn.

I have modified your example to this

```
div {
    background:
    linear-gradient(27deg, red 17px, transparent 17px) 0 20px,
    linear-gradient(207deg, green 20px, transparent 20px) 40px 0px,
    linear-gradient(90deg, pink 40px, transparent 40px),
    linear-gradient(white 25%, orange 25%, orange 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
    background-size: 80px 80px;
}
```

[image: background2]

The blue rectangle is the base size of the background.

The first line, creates the red triangle, with an angle of 27 deg (that is pointing aprox to the 2 o'clock,  being red 17 pixels, then changing to transparent instantly. The cobnfusing part is here. The 0 o position would have this triangle as the first image that I posted. Setting the position to 0px 20px, we set it downwards. Since this is arepeating gradient, it now appears high in the blue square (the equivalent, easier to understand, would be position = 0px -60px. You set it at 20 px from the top, so *touching* the border

The second line in the style creates the green triangle. The angle is 207, so goes in the opposite direction of the red one. the size is 20px, approx the same than the red, but it is positioned at 40px in the y. If it was not positioned, it would be sitting in the top right corner of the square (just the first image that I posted, rotated 180 deg. Moving it 40 px to the right, makes it look as if it had entered the neighbourghing square.

Maybe the best way to understand this it to play with every value in dev tools of the browser.

Comment: This is helpful, but I am still feeling overwhelmed by how much CSS there is to understand. Could you interpret a few lines for me in this fashion: linear-gradient(<start point>, <color> <width>... please?